# функция в классе массив

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток!
У меня есть класс массив.

Я создаю массив

```
class Matrix
{
private:
int line, column, **mas;
public:
 Matrix doTask(Matrix matrix);
Matrix(int n = 1, int m = 1 ) : line(n), column(m)
{
    mas = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new int[m];
    }
}

Matrix(const Matrix &masToCopy) // конструктор копирования
{
    line = masToCopy.line;
    column= masToCopy.column;

    mas = new int*[line];   // для новой копии
for (int i= 0; i <line; i++)
    mas[i] = new int[column];

for (int i = 0; i<line; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        mas[i][j] = masToCopy.mas[i][j];
}

friend istream& operator >> (istream &in, Matrix &el) //перегрузка >>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < el.line; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < el.column; j++)
        {
            in >> el.mas[i][j];

        }
    }
    return in;
}

friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Matrix &el) //перегрузка <<
{
    for (int i = 0; i < el.line; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < el.column; j++)
        {
            out << el.mas[i][j];
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    return out;
}
};


   int main()
{
Matrix Task(4, 3);
cout << "\nВведите массив размером 4 на 3 \n";
cin >> Task;
cout << Task.doTask(Task);
 }
```

И пытаюсь передать его в функцию, которая увеличивает все отрицательные нечетные числа в 2 раза

```
Matrix Matrix::doTask(Matrix matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++)
        {
            if (matrix.mas[i][j] < 0 && matrix.mas[i][j] % 2 != 0)
            {
                matrix.mas[i][j] *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Но строчка с if вызывает исключение. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Matrix Task(4, 3);` - это не создание массива. Я даже не знаю, что это. Может покажете полный код?

Comment: @KoVadim добавила полный код

Comment: Так как передача в `doTask` (и возврат результата) у вас делается по значению, сразу возникает подозрение, что проблема в плохо написанном конструкторе копирования. Вы нам его, однако, не показываете. Отдельный вопрос - что это за метод такой `doTask`, который обрабатывает посторонний объект, а не `*this`. Зачем тогда этот `doTask` вообще является методом `Matrix`, если с `*this` он не работает вообще? Это статический метод? Вот этот вызов в `main` - `Task.doTask(Task)` - это просто феерически странно. Зачем объект `Task` передается сам в себя?

Comment: @AnT Я добавила конструктор копирования. Я ещё плохо разобралась с *this. А задание- создать отдельную функцию, которая получает cсылку на массив и не является методом класса или дружественной функцией

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде вывода написана белиберда

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++)
                    ^
```

Отлавливать ошибки "по невнимательности" вы должны уметь самостоятельно. StackOverflow - это не сайт и разряда "найдите мои опечатки за меня". Удивляет также использование "магических констант" 4 и 3, в то время как у вас в классе есть поля, задающие размер массива.

Отдельно стоит заметить, что параметр оператора `<<` должен быть ссылкой на константу

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Matrix &el)
                                           ^^^^^
```

иначе ваше `cout << Task.doTask(Task);` является некорректным. (Он компилируется в MSVC лишь благодаря одному из расширений языка.)

Отдельный вопрос, как я уже писал в комментариях: что это за метод такой `doTask`, который обрабатывает посторонний объект, а не `*this`. Зачем тогда этот `doTask` вообще является методом `Matrix`, если с `*this` он не работает вообще? Вот этот вызов в `main` - `Task.doTask(Task)` - это просто феерически странно. Зачем объект `Task` передается сам в свой собственный метод? (Это совсем не обязательно является ошибкой в общем случае, но зачем это нужно именно в вашем случае - не ясно.)

Если вы уж хотите иметь такой метод, то сделайте так

```
Matrix Matrix::doTask() const
{
   Matrix result(*this);

   for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
       {
           if (result.mas[i][j] < 0 && result.mas[i][j] % 2 != 0)
           {
               result.mas[i][j] *= 2;
           }
       }
   }

   return result;
}
```

и соответственно

```
cout << Task.doTask();
```

Comment: толком ещё не разобралась и делала больше методом тыка, чем осознанно